# how will I get the button that I clicked in PHP post multiple submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I am using multiple submit button in a single form.

I will get the button I clicked, in normal post. But when I am using javascript this.form.submit(), I am not getting the button that I have clicked.

Is there any solution to identify the button without using hidden fields.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" >
 $("input#add").click(function(e) {  
  e.preventDefault();
        $("<div>Do you want to continue ? </div>").dialog({
         modal: true,
         buttons: {
                "Ok": function() {         
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    this.form.submit();
                },
                "Cancel": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
 });
  
  $("input#subtract").click(function(e) {  
  e.preventDefault();
        $("<div>Do you want to continue ? </div>").dialog({
         modal: true,
         buttons: {
                "Ok": function() {         
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    this.form.submit();
                },
                "Cancel": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
 });
</script>
  
<form name="my_form" action="processor.php" method="post"> 
<br> <br> 
Enter a number: <input type="text" name="number" size="5"> 
<br> <br> 
<input type="submit" name="add" id="add"value="Add 10"> 
<input type="submit" name="subtract" id="subtract" value="Subtract 10"> 
</form>
```

The server code that I need to check as follows.

```html
if($this->input->post("add")) 
{
 $save_status = 1;
}

if($this->input->post("subtract")) 
{
 $save_status = 2;
    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you have a small mistake, You have not closed the `<script>`

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
  $("input#add").click(function(e) {  
    this.form.submit();
    $("input#add").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  });

  $("input#subtract").click(function(e) {  
    this.form.submit();
    $("input#subtract").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  });
<script>// this line it shud be </script>
```

This should help you.

IN `processor.php`,

```
print_r($_POST);// you should be able to get expected result.
```

see [demo](http://main.xfiddle.com/97edf357/mainphp.php) here

Main php code [here](http://phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C?php%5Cn?%3E%5Cn%3Chtml%3E%5Cn%5Ct%3Cbody%3E%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%3Cform%20name=%22my_form%22%20action=%22test.php%22%20method=%22post%22%3E%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%3Cbr%3E%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%3Cbr%3E%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5CtEnter%20a%20number:%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%3Cinput%20type=%22text%22%20name=%22number%22%20size=%225%22%3E%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%3Cbr%3E%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%3Cbr%3E%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%3Cinput%20type=%22submit%22%20name=%22add%22%20id=%22add%22%20value=%22Add%2010%22%3E%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%3Cinput%20type=%22submit%22%20name=%22subtract%22%20id=%22subtract%22%20value=%22Subtract%2010%22%3E%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%3C/form%3E%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%3Cscript%20src=%22http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js%22%3E%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%3Cscript%20type=%22text/javascript%22%20%3E%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct$%28%22input%2523add%22%29.click%28function%28e%29%20%7B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ctthis.form.submit%28%29;%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct$%28%22input%2523add%22%29.attr%28%27disabled%27,%20%27disabled%27%29;%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%7D%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%29;%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct$%28%22input%2523subtract%22%29.click%28function%28e%29%20%7B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ctthis.form.submit%28%29;%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct$%28%22input%2523subtract%22%29.attr%28%27disabled%27,%20%27disabled%27%29;%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%7D%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%20%29;%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%3C/script%3E%5Cn%5Ct%3C/body%3E%5Cn%3C/html%3E)

After form submit code [here](http://phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C?php%5Cn//%20Using%20environment%20library%20fiddle_envlib.php%20to%20files%20saved%20under%20user%20id%20folder%5Cnprint_r($_POST);%5Cn?%3E)

Comment: please add this in question. as it is not formatted, its haed to go through the code.

Comment: e.preventDefault(); will prevent the default behavoiur. Did u check the demo. Its working.

Comment: yes, I have checked.., that is working, I have updated the confirm box in question

Comment: you want to ask confirmation before submitting?? That should work which is there in updated code of your's.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92696/discussion-between-niranjan-n-raju-and-sumesh).

Comment: I am not getting posted button ,, because it is disabled immediately after form submit. I think disabled buttons will not be there in post

Comment: just remove that disabled and try once.

Comment: Y do u want to disable that button?

Comment: please check the chat box

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(document).on('click','#add',function() {  
      this.form.submit();
    $("#add").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  });

  $(document).on('click','#subtract',function() {  
    this.form.submit();
    $("#subtract").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  });
  });
</script>

<form name="my_form" action="#" method="post"> 
<br> <br> 
Enter a number: <input type="text" name="number" size="5"> 
<br> <br> 
<input type="button" name="add" id="add"value="Add 10"> 
<input type="button" name="subtract" id="subtract" value="Subtract 10"> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as per @Niranjan, the `</script>` should be there in your script. Apart from this, in your script, you can have a hidden input field. Say "clicked_button".

```
<input type="hidden" name="clicked_button" id="clicked_button">
```

And in your Javascript:

```
$("input#add").click(function(e) {  
    $("#clicked_button").val("add_button");
    this.form.submit();
    $("input#add").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});

$("input#subtract").click(function(e) {  
    $("#clicked_button").val("substract_button");
    this.form.submit();
    $("input#subtract").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

And now in your PHP script, in form submission code - if you print following POST variables; you should be able to get the button which you clicked:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Then you can put either switch case or if-else condition to perform your desired action.

Comment: Thanks, I am not allowed to use hidden fields in my code, I need to know whether a solution is there... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try type as button.

As you already have two separate click event bind in jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same in simple way by using ONCLICK with input type 'button'

```
    <script type="text/javascript" >  

  function  submitForm(id){
  alert(id);
  $('#my_form').submit();
  $("input#"+id).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
</script>

<form name="my_form" id="my_form" action="processor.php" method="post"> 
<br> <br> 
Enter a number: <input type="text" name="number" size="5"> 
<br> <br> 
<input type="button" name="add" id="add"value="Add 10" onClick="submitForm(this.id)"> 
<input type="button" name="subtract" id="subtract" value="Subtract 10"  onClick="submitForm(this.id)"> 
</form>
```